# Is it possible for an Airbus A380 to operate with 8 of the largest geared turbofans instead of 4 Trent 900 engines?

Tags: airbus-a380

Is it possible for an Airbus A380 to operate with eight of the largest geared turbofans instead of four Trent 900 engines? Would it be fuel efficient? What would be the total thrust of the engines?

Comment: Why 8, why not 6. Random question. "*What would be the total thrust of the engines?*", well if you know which engine is the largest GTF, then don't you have already the answer? "*Would it be fuel efficient?*": After redesigning the wings, maybe. What do you mean by "fuel efficient", a phrase you use a lot in your A380 questions?

Comment: This is a subset of your other question. I’m relatively sure that rated thrust of „the largest GTF“ should be a googleable number, is it not?

Comment: They really want you to know this isn't some fun site like Quora, it seems. You might ask there instead.

Answer (score 2):

The current largest geared turbofan is the [PW1100G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_PW1000G). The highest thrust variant is the PW1130G which provides 147.28kN of thrust. Eight of these would provide 1178kN total thrust.

The [Trent 900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_900) provides 340kN of thrust, the 4 engines on the A380 provide a total of 1360kN of thrust. This means that 8 PW1130G engines would leave the A380 a bit under-powered.

Would it be efficient? Probably. Most of the efficiency of an airplane comes from the engines. The PW1100G are newer and more efficient than the Trent 900 engines. There would be some losses due to higher installation drag but probably not enough to offset the efficiency.

Comment: Pro efficiency: Newer engines; optimised design; more of them means less total thrust required to cover engine failure (provided certification allows credit). Against efficiency: More installation drag per engine; less efficient wing (there’s no undisturbed part of wing anymore - engines everywhere); less efficient high pressure sections (ratio of blade gaps/engine diameter larger). Effect unclear: weight changes due pylon/wing structure & more complicated fuel system with smaller diameter pipes etc.

Comment: +1. Just wondering if there would be a customer for an A380 with 8 engines to maintain. Maybe because it would have the ETOPS 600.

Comment: I’m definitely not claiming my list to be comprehensive in any way, I should add.

Comment: @mins there are barely any customers for an A380 with 4 engines to maintain. :P